# Delete all files within a directory within a specific subfolder

Tags: windows-command-prompt

I have seen and tried a few solutions online but these don't seem to be working. I don't need a recursive function. Basically I have a directory with numerous subfolders which all have subfolders of name "leaf", I wish to remove all files within each "leaf" subfolder.

This on a Windows machine where I cannot install anything.

C;/directory/folder1/leaf
C;/directory/folder2/leaf
C;/directory/folder3/leaf

Answer (score 0):

This would be a little easier if you used gnuwin32 tools to provide Linux tools in windows, Cygwin or even best WSL. It's been a while.. but will this work??

If you need this done in a single command I haven't done windows in so long I can't help.. .but if you are willing to use gnuwin32 or install windows subsystem for Linux (which is awesome by the way)

If you can do it in like a batch

@echo off
del C:/directory/foldedr1/leaf/*
del C:/directory/Folder2/leaf
del C:/directory/folder3/leaf

Sorry for any typos.  I've been up all night working

If you whave wsl...

for i in /mnt/c/directory/folder1/leaf  /mnt/c/directory/folder2/leaf /mnt/c/directory/folder3/leaf/;
do
rm -f * (or rm -rf * if youw ant dirs in leaf deleted also
done

Don't forget the done to close it out.

Sorry fi this isn't what you're looking for. Just tryhing to help... you can run wsl on most windows 10 versions now I think and cygwin can run anywhere. but gnuwin32 tools lets you use linux command in windows CMD without any issues. http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

Take care and please efeel free to reach out if you have questions. I'm going o be son bu tI'm gonna be up in about 2 hours.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Hope you got some rest!

Answer (score 0):

from WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux):

```
rm -rf /mnt/c/directory/*/leaf/*
```